# How to grab a numeric id in URI?

Tags: regex, url, uri, numeric

I need to grab the first numeric ID after `#/`.
For example, I would like only grab 68 and 112 in these URI:

```
//www.domain.tld/category/14-457-myproduct.html#/68-attribute-fm_300_224_39_b

//www.domain.tld/category/36-578-myproduct.html#/112-attribute-fm_489_471_51_w
```

I even tried to split the URI in several steps, but it does not work once on my site (Smarty template).

Comment: Try using a capturing group `#/(\d+)` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/IHfGpI/1) or to match any non digits between the forward slash and the digits and then use a capturing group  try `#/\D*(\d+)`

Comment: Thanks, but that not works, with these two regex.

Comment: Can you show the code that you tried? Or how this did not work? Try escaping the forward slash `#\/(\d+)` or if applicable use a different delimiter  `~#/(\d+)~`

Comment: You can see below... Same conditions (with start and end slash, of course)

Comment: To match them all use `preg_match_all` like for example https://3v4l.org/jcHvf

Comment: With for example a `~` as delimeter and match one that could be `preg_match('~#/(\d+)~', '//www.domain.tld/category/14-457-myproduct.html#/68-attribute-fm_300_224_39_b', $matches);
print_r($matches[1]); //68`

Comment: That works too: `{$temp = preg_match('~#/(\d+)~', $product.url, $match)}` then simply `{$match[1]}` to display grabbed ID. It's shorter, thanks for help ;)

Comment: If you only want to get `$match[1]` you don't need `$temp` because that is what `preg_match` returns.

Comment: Yes, I know. Please see explanation about `$temp` below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like this :

```
<?php

$pattern = "/#\/([0-9])*-/";
$url1  = "//www.domain.tld/category/14-457-myproduct.html#/68-attribute-fm_300_224_39_b";
$url2 = "//www.domain.tld/category/36-578-myproduct.html#/112-attribute-fm_489_471_51_w";

echo getNumber($url1, $pattern);
echo "\n";
echo getNumber($url2, $pattern);

function getNumber($url, $pattern){
    preg_match($pattern,  $url, $matches);

    return substr($matches[0], 2, -1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That works in Smarty :)
First: `{$temp = preg_match('/#\/([0-9])*-/', $product.url, $match)}`
Then: `{$match[0]|substr:2:-1}`. Why `$temp` assignation? Because I didn't find any other way not to display the operation result, just for that.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know Smarty, I can't tell you why `$temp` assignation is needed...